# Conservation of signs of eigenvalues of metric tensor

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, linear-algebra

The metric of an arbitrary spacetime can be transformed into the Minkowski metric because

$$g_{\mu \nu } = J_{\mu }^{\alpha } J_{\nu }^{\beta} \eta_{\alpha \beta }\tag{1}.$$

Gives ten equation for 16 independent variables, namely the terms in the Jacobian.

In matrix form this would be

$$g = J \eta  J^{T}\tag{2}.$$

In a lecture series I'm following it is said that [Sylvester's law of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia) should apply and that therefore the number of positive and negative eigenvalues of an arbitrary metric should be the same as that of the Minkowski metric.

I believe this theorem only holds if $J$ were an orthonormal matrix but

$$JJ^{T}=I\tag{3}.$$

Gives us another 10 equations to solve but 16 independent variables cannot, in general, solve a system of 20 equations.
What am I missing? Am I wrong in saying that the Sylvester law holds only if $J$ is orthonormal?

Comment: The theorem doesn't require $J$ to be orthonormal; where did you get this impression?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: You are confusing the diagonalisation procedure of symmetric marices which act as operators and the analgous procedure for quadratic forms. The former is performed by orthogonal matrices, the latter with non-singular matrices.

Comment: Ahh yeah you're right. I wish there was an easier, linear algebra level proof for this theorem...

Comment: Related on MathSE: Why is "Sylvester's law of inertia" called in such a way?  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/6906/532409